# Scala: initializing a val in a trait based on user input

Tags: scala, traits

I have a trait in my project which I use as my configurations file, something like that:

```
trait config {
   val people = Seq("John","Jessie")
}
```

This trait is used with `extends`) in all my objects (except the main one). What I would like to do is to assign a different value to `people` based on the `args` received in my `main` function from the user, so I'll have something like:

```
trait config {
   val people = args.head match {
      case "A" => Seq("John","Jessie")
      case "B" => Seq("Bill","James","Brad")
      case _ => Seq("Jimmy")
 }}
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: This is unlikely the best pattern for Configuration type data. You could have a trait that contained whatever config data you want, but then you would have to include it and populate it for every object. It kind of sounds like you want to define the trait _with the config data already there_ so you can just extend it without having to populate it, but that's impossible. However, if you could it wouldt be a bad idea because that data would not be shared. It would be different actual objects in each object extending it which would be inefficient. I would research Dependency Injection.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally committed my comment before it was complete since I apparently am not good at using this editor. Who knew new-lines were so hard? :)

Comment: then what is a good way to inject all the config parameters to all required objects and classes?

Comment: First, you can only define `trait` this way inside you `main` method (or further down), but maybe it's what you want to do. Second, I would suggest moving `match` part out of `trait` so it's not get executed whenever you instantiate extended class.

Comment: @IdanWaisman If `match` is done outside of `trait` the data will be shared. A little work to call setter every time you instantiate, but not that much.

Comment: @VictorMoroz if I move the `match` part out of the trait, how will it be a part of `config`?

Comment: `val peopleOuter = args.head match ...; trait config { val people = peopleOuter; ... }`, so you do `match` once and only copy reference when instantiating your extended config.

Comment: The "cake pattern" is where you use traits to establish such dependencies, and your App mix-in configuration ties it together. But the pattern is not considered an unqualified success. Search for that term and Reader.

Answer (score 2):

What you ask is possible:

```
trait config {
  app: App =>

  lazy val people = args.head match {
    case "A" => Seq("John","Jessie")
    case "B" => Seq("Bill","James","Brad")
    case _ => Seq("Jimmy")
  }
}

object Main extends App with config {
  people.mkString
}
```

or you can reduce the trait to make it work for other types than App.

```
trait config {
  protected def args: Array[String]

  lazy val people = args.head match {
    case "A" => Seq("John","Jessie")
    case "B" => Seq("Bill","James","Brad")
    case _ => Seq("Jimmy")
  }
}
```

However, as already pointed out, it is not a good pattern.

If you want to provide a system wide config you might want to have a look at [Typesafe Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config)

Comment: how do I preform the actions I need with Typesafe?